# Redis Streams data exchange between services

Tags: service, redis, stream, microservices

I'm working on microservices with Redis Streams.

Basically, the **service A is sending jobs to service B** using Redis Streams (XADD).
Once service B is receiving a job through Redis Streams, **this service execute an HTTP request to an external API**, parse the result and XACK the job. During this time **service A is waiting for data coming from service B**.

What is the right way to send the parsed result of the HTTP request from service B to service A which is waiting for data ?

Possible answers I think about:

- Use another Redis Streams (XREAD or XREADGROUP) on service A which is waiting for incomming data sent from B but I need to provide a stream name where to sent data into the message sent from A to B.
- Use another Redis data type like lists which can use blocking requests (BLPOP, BRPOP...) but how to know if the data comming into this list is the right message ? Maybe I need to use a unique ID somewhere.
- Use pub/sub but I don't really like this solution as there is no history or persistent data.

I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Can service A send more than a single request to Service B in parallel or is it sending one request and immediately waiting for response?

Comment: Service A is synchronous and service B is asynchronous. So A is sending a request and directly wait for a response. But service B can handle multiple requests at a time.

Comment: I don't think there's a "right way", but I'd use another stream